# Are there any Star Trek episode that feature only regular/recurring cast and no guest stars?

Tags: star-trek

In a typical Star Trek episode you have the regular cast (i.e. the ones listed in the intro), possibly some recurring characters (e.g. Garak or Lwaxana Troi), and usually also at least 1 main guest actor/actress who has a significant role in the plot.

There's typically also non-speaking background extras and some random non-speaking dude at the helm, but I'm not counting those.

So I'm curious: are there any Star Trek episodes from any series that feature no speaking guest cast, but only regular, recurring and background cast?

The (widely loved) TNG clip show ['Shades of gray'](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Shades_of_Gray_(episode)) fits the description for the newly filmed parts (only the main cast and the universe's favorite recurring transporter chief Miles O'Brien), but the flashbacks do contain other guest actors.

I've looked at the list of [bottle shows](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bottle_show), but can't find any there.

Comment: “The (widely loved) TNG clip show 'Shades of gray'” — It's like The Menagerie, only much cheaper!

Comment: Does [ENT: Dead Stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Stop) count? The only guest star was Roxann Dawson (Torres) as the voice of the computer. She's regular cast but on another series...

Comment: Does [ENT: These are the Voyages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/These_Are_the_Voyages...) count? The show had a variety of guest stars but all (with the exception of Shran who was a recurring character on Enterprise) cast regulars from *other Star Trek shows*.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think about regulars from another series, but that fits the spirit of my question, so I feel they count

Comment: @Valorum: Jeffrey Combs, of course, might be the king of Start Trek. He did not only play a recurring character on ENT but also *two* (or 6 depending on how you count, playing 5 different clones of Weyoun) recurring characters on DS9 (in one episode even both of them), plus appearing as one-off characters on VOY, ENT and two different ones on DS9, not to mention various voices in Star Trek video games.

Comment: I wonder... I remembered the Voyager episode "Parallax" because it was spent entirely on the ship with no outside contact. However the wiki pages list two "Guest stars" anyway. Looking closer though it seems that these "guest stars" were there for several episodes each. So... how many episodes does a character need to appear in before they are considered "regular"?

Comment: @Vilx- - I counted them as recurring if they appeared beyond any story arc in which they were the main or supporting-main character, so if it was just down to Seska and Carey, I would have included it on my list. In the case of Parallax, I discounted it because of Justin Williams' appearance as Crewman Jarvin in that single episode.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Several episodes of Voyager had no guest stars who weren't either future/former regular cast members or recurring cast members.**

- [VOY: Parturition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parturition_(Star_Trek:_Voyager)) **featured no guest stars.**
- [VOY: The Gift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gift_(Star_Trek:_Voyager)) featured a single guest star; former cast regular Kes (Jennifer Lien).
- [VOY: Course: Oblivion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Course:_Oblivion) **featured no guest stars**.
- [VOY: Human Error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_Error_(Star_Trek:_Voyager)) featured a single guest star; recurring character Icheb (Manu Intiraymi).

---

**Several episodes of TNG had no guest stars who weren't either future/former regular cast members or recurring cast members.**

- [TNG: Time Squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Squared_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation)) featured two guest stars; recurring guest Katherine Pulaski (Diana Muldaur) and recurring guest Miles O'Brien (Colm Meaney).
- [TNG: Shades of Gray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shades_of_Gray_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation)) featured two guest stars; recurring guest Katherine Pulaski (Diana Muldaur) and recurring guest Miles O'Brien (Colm Meaney).
- [TNG: Parallels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallels_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation)) featured two guest stars; recurring guest Alyssa Ogawa (Patti Yasutake) and former cast regular Wesley Crusher (Wil Wheaton).

---

**Several episodes of DS9 had no guest stars who weren't either future/former regular cast members or recurring cast members.**

- [DS9: Fascination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fascination_(Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine)) featured three guest stars; recurring guest Lwaxana Troi (Majel Barrett), recurring guest Bareil (Philip Anglim) and recurring guest Keiko O'Brien (Rosalind Chao).
- [DS9: Heart of Stone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_of_Stone_(Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine)) featured four guest stars; future cast regular Rom (Max Grodénchik), future cast regular Nog (Aron Eisenberg), recurring voice actor Majel Barrett and recurring guest Female Changeling (Salome Jens).
- [DS9: Return to Grace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_to_Grace) featured three guest stars; recurring guest Gul Dukat (Marc Alaimo), recurring guest Ziyal (in this instance played by Cyia Batten) and recurring guest Damar (Casey Biggs).
- [DS9: The Ascent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ascent_(Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine)) featured two guest stars; future cast regular Rom (Max Grodénchik) and future cast regular Nog (Aron Eisenberg)
- [DS9: Call to Arms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_to_Arms_(Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine)) featured six(!) guest stars; recurring guest Garak (Andrew J. Robinson), recurring guest Weyoun (Jeffrey Combs), recurring guest Gul Dukat (Marc Alaimo), recurring guest General Martok (J. G. Hertzler), recurring guest Leeta (Chase Masterson) and recurring guest Ziyal (in this instance played by Melanie Smith)
- [DS9: Behind the Lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behind_the_Lines_(Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine)) featured seven(!) guest stars; recurring guest Weyoun (Jeffrey Combs), recurring guest Gul Dukat (Marc Alaimo), future cast regular Rom (Max Grodénchik), future cast regular Nog (Aron Eisenberg), recurring guest Damar (Casey Biggs), recurring guest Admiral Ross (Barry Jenner) and recurring guest Female Changeling (Salome Jens)
- [DS9: Favor the Bold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favor_the_Bold) featured eleven(!!) guest stars; recurring guest Garak (Andrew J. Robinson), recurring guest Weyoun (Jeffrey Combs), recurring guest Gul Dukat (Marc Alaimo), future cast regular Nog (Aron Eisenberg), recurring guest Damar (Casey Biggs), recurring guest Admiral Ross (Barry Jenner), recurring guest Female Changeling (Salome Jens), recurring guest General Martok (J. G. Hertzler), recurring guest Leeta (Chase Masterson) and recurring guest Ziyal (in this instance played by Melanie Smith)
- [DS9: Sacrifice of Angels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacrifice_of_Angels) featured nine(!) guest stars; recurring guest Garak (Andrew J. Robinson), recurring guest Weyoun (Jeffrey Combs),  recurring guest Damar (Casey Biggs), recurring guest Gul Dukat (Marc Alaimo), future cast regular Rom (Max Grodénchik), recurring guest Female Changeling (Salome Jens), recurring guest General Martok (J. G. Hertzler), recurring guest Leeta (Chase Masterson) and recurring guest Ziyal (in this instance played by Melanie Smith).
- [DS9: Waltz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waltz_(Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine)) featured three guest stars; recurring guest Garak (Andrew J. Robinson), recurring guest Weyoun (Jeffrey Combs) and recurring guest Damar (Casey Biggs).
- [DS9: Afterimage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afterimage_(Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine)) featured two guest stars; recurring guest Garak (Andrew J. Robinson) and recurring background character Morn (Mark Allen Shepherd).
- [DS9: Treachery, Faith, and the Great River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treachery,_Faith,_and_the_Great_River) featured six guest stars;  recurring guest Weyoun (Jeffrey Combs), recurring guest Damar (Casey Biggs),  recurring guest Martok (J. G. Hertzler), future cast regular Rom (Max Grodénchik), future cast regular Nog (Aron Eisenberg) and recurring guest Female Changeling (Salome Jens).

**Several episodes of ST: Enterprise had no guest stars who weren't either future/former regular cast members or recurring cast members.**

- [ENT: Shuttlepod One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuttlepod_One) **featured no guest stars**
- [ENT: Doctor's Orders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor%27s_Orders_(Star_Trek:_Enterprise)) **featured no guest stars**
- [ENT: Observer Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_Effect_(Star_Trek:_Enterprise)) **featured no guest stars**
- [ENT: Dead Stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Stop) featured a single guest star, Voyager regular Roxann Dawson.
- [ENT: These are the Voyages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/These_Are_the_Voyages...) had six guest stars; TNG cast regular William Riker (Jonathan Frakes), TNG cast regular Deanna Troi (Marina Sirtis), TNG cast regular Data (Brent Spiner), TNG cast regular Jean-Luc Picard (Patrick Stewart), TOS cast regular James T. Kirk (William Shatner) and recurring guest Shran (Jeffrey Combs)

Comment: I'm torn on adding I, Borg. Hugh recurred in Picard (three episodes plus a flashback) as well as turning up in two more episodes of TNG

Comment: ['Power Play'](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Power_Play_(episode)) has Ryan Reid as 'Transporter Technician' ("the role I was born to play!"), but aside from that, it's just the same old regular jabronis.

Comment: Pulaski is considered a recurring guest and not a regular?  I thought she was a regular *for that season*, like Tasha.

Comment: @tbrookside - Worthy of its own question, perhaps. From what I've read, she was asked to star on the show (didn't audition) and was given a one year contract. Presumably her agent negotiated the "special guest star" status to compensate her for the short-term nature of the role.

Comment: May I ask how you gathered all this data? :O

Comment: @PedroA - A combination of going through the credits on IMDB and going through the credits on Wikipedia. Also I've seen every episode of these about a dozen times

Comment: So the category definitions here go by credits? I would have guessed Meaney as Miles O'Brien was a regular.

Comment: @aschepler - He was always a guest star on TNG. Latterly he was regular cast on DS9

Comment: VOY: Parturition had an alien ... while it did not speak, it had more to do than a mere "background extra".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - It wasn't listed as a guest star.

Comment: @Valorum - this is a brilliant answer, but every time I look at it I am bothered by the series missing from the list -- how can the list be complete without TOS?  It is not as if you don't know -- you mentioned it in a comment on another answer...

Comment: @Basya - I assumed at the time that PMar would update their answer...

Answer (score 13):

ST:TOS episode "The Tholian Web" featured only recurring characters.

Comment: Except for the Tholians, but they didn't have many lines.

Comment: If you're doing TOS episodes, you might want to add *The Enemy Within* and *The Immunity Syndrome* to your list.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis - Sean Morgan was also listed as additional cast in the credits (one of two named appearances) but not as a guest star.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis They had lines all over the screen!

Comment: "The Tholian Web" was my first thought.  IMDB confirms this is, pointing out that it was not only constrained to series regulars but also includes all of them (Sulu and Chekhov in the same episode!).  IMDB also suggests "The Enemy Within" and "The Immunity Syndrome" as meeting the criteria.  On the other hand, Wikipedia lists nine guest appearances for the Tholian Web, including Barbara Babcock who provided for the Tholian commander and various crew members.  Spot checking, it seems like the uncredited crew members were recurring crew members in many episodes.

Answer (score 7):

If we're counting *Star Trek: Enterprise*, the episode "Shuttlepod One", which is a bottle episode of Malcom and Trip on the titular vessel, has no guest stars nor background performers (the only *Star Trek* episode to hold that distinction.

Note: Only seven characters/actors appeared on that episode, all of whom are regular cast members (Archer, T'Pol, Reed, Tucker, Mayweather (voice only), Phlox, and Sato

In the episode *Doctor's Orders*, which features Phlox hallucinating whilst the rest of the crew is in stasis, there are a number of uncredited co-stars and some archive footage is used

The episode *Observer Effect* also features only the main cast, and a couple of uncredited co-stars, and the main cast are playing not only their usual characters, but non-corporeal aliens in the bodies of their usual characters

Source: [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Shuttlepod_One_(episode)) (credit goes to Valorum for pointing out the other two episodes)